# Setting up a watchfolder

Tags: macos, bash, ffmpeg, cron

I want to make a folder that I can put any video file into and have ffmpeg catch it and spit it out as an mp4 and remove the non-mp4 file.

I have the following:

```
for f in *.*;
do ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4
-movflags +faststart -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p "${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

I plan on setting up a cron job to run the following on a specified folder every hour. However, I'm curious if there is a better way to do this? I'm assuming if a job isn't finished within the hour ffmpeg will start making duplicates?

Comment: If you use a cronjob, first move a new video to an other directory before starting ffmpeg to avoid duplicate running jobs with same video.

Comment: That would work, or check for an .mp4 file of the same name and abort if there is one. Build some logic into the shellscript. Depending on resources, you might want to limit things to processing one at a time, for instance. And if you build that into the script you can call the script more frequently without penalty - if ffmpeg is running, the script aborts without doing anything other than checking if it's running. You could call a script like that every minute without much processing wasted.

Comment: I was also working on some logic as that, I did however come across an app called "iwatch" (extremely hard to Google with a certain Apple product on the market) that seems to be tackling the same problem I'm looking to solve: http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html and http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2012/11/14/watch-a-folder-for-new-files-and-convert-them-with-bash-script/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I got iwatch up and running with an smb share in Xubuntu, this should suffice for 3 users or so. I haven't had a chance to max out the job requests.